# Many-to-many relationship with EF code first and static table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5, and a code first approach.

I have a `Product` class, which can have zero-or-more `ProductColors`. The colors are prepopulated in the database using seeding. The color table should not be populated with new items using EF as it is a static list of items that will not grow. Colors are reused in many products.

My model classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductColor> Colors { get; set; }
}

public class ProductColor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbMigrationsConfiguration`:

```
protected override void Seed(... context)
{
    context.ProductColors.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.ID,
        new ProductColor(1, "White"),
        new ProductColor(2, "Black"),
        new ProductColor(3, "Red"));
}
```

In my `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(x => x.Colors).WithMany();
}

public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

My `Products` are created from a viewmodel object, both when they are created for the first time, and also later when they are edited:

```
Product product = new Product { ID = productViewModel.ID };

product.Colors = new List<ProductColor>();
foreach (int colorId in productViewModel.SelectedColorIds)
{
    ProductColor productColor = productColors.Find(m => m.ID == colorId);
    product.Colors.Add(productColor);
}
```

They are saved in the database like this when created:

```
db.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
```

And like this when they are edited:

```
db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

EF generates `Products`, `ProductColor` and `ProductProductColor` tables just fine initially. When the products are first created and saved, the colors are properly being saved in the `ProductProductColor` table.

But when I edit/modify the `Product` and `Colors` collection, the colors are not being updated in the database. Seems it doesn't recognize that the Colors collection has been modified. How can I make it so?

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I wanted to include all the elements in case someone needs the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Instead of create a new `Product` instance (using the same ID as previously), I fetch the product from the database.

```
IQueryable<Product> products = 
    from p in db.Products.Include("Colors")
    select p;
Product product = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(products, p => p.ID == id);
```

When I then change the `Colors` collection, it seems the tracking of items is working and serialized correctly into the database.

After some reading to understand why, I see fetching the product from the database creates a Proxy object that keeps track of the collection for me. When creating a `Product` manually, it is not able to track changes to collections.